# In iOS 7 is there a way to display an image over the tab bar?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am looking for away to display a static image over the tab bar? The image will not cover the entire tab bar, just part of it. But I still want to be able to use the tabs.

I am looking to do something like this. I can get the images in the tab bar, but I wan to display the image over the tab bar like image in the middle here:

[image]

Comment: do you want to set the static image on selected tabbaritem?

Comment: No, I just want to display it all the times where ever the tab bar is shown. It will have zero functionality.

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Comment: @Cedric if you want to couple Tabbar and Image together like the Gebriel.Masaana's screenshot, then I would recommend doing it as in his answer.

Comment: I added an image of what I am hoping to do. Hope this helps you get the idea.

Comment: Did you try my answer? after seeing your image, I think that adding the image in window should work for you.

Comment: @Selvin I have been trying your answer. I think the problem with your answer not working is I am using tab bar controller that Xcode provides in the storyboard. I implemented it using the menu Editor>Embed In>Tab Bar Controller. Do you have another solution for this type of implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate an UIImageView with the image and add it in the Appdelegate's Window directly over the tab bar. Make sure you disable the user interaction of the ImageView before adding it on the window.

It will be there over the tab bar without taking any action.

**Update:**

Get the window from appDelegate,

```
Appdelegate *appDelegate = ((Appdelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).delegate;
UIWindow *appDelegateWindow = appDelegate.window;
```

Then allocate the image view.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[imageView sizeToFit];
```

set the frames for the imageview and add it to the window.

```
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,380,50,50)];
[appDelegateWindow addSubView:imageView];
```

Comment: Does this need to be done within each UIViewController? Or is there another way to add it to the App Delegate Window?

Comment: You wouldnt need to set it with each view controller. You are adding it to the subview of the tab bar. It will show regardlesws of what tab you are in.

Comment: I have tried this a couple of times... where do you suggest I implement your solution?

Comment: I figured it out and it works great. I was implementing in my viewDidLoad method instead of viewDidAppear in my UITabBarController subclass. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that in **AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Allocate an imageView
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageTabBar.png"]];

    //UITabBarController should be your rootViewController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;

    //set the imageView
    [tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:imageView];

    // Send ImageView back
    [tabBarController.tabBar sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
}
```

**This is the result in the Simulator**:

[image: example with this code]

Comment: You can also use insertSubview:atIndex: with index = 0, rather than sendSubviewToBack.  Also, it looks like the example has the image clipped. If you want it to show outside the bounds of the tab bar then you can set clipsToBounds = NO.